# exit menu doesn't work properly

Tags: android

I have created a menu and put an exit button on it. Now when I click on it, it behaves like a back button and closes the activity. Menu items display correctly but when i select, then nothing happened. Please tell me to fix this problem.

Here's menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/exit_menu"
          android:title="Exit"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Here's MainActivity.java

```
package com.testing.exitMenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.exit_menu:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(exit);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only activity in your app, just call `finish()` and the activity will close.

Exit buttons are generally an anti-pattern on Android. Users shouldn't have to exit your app, they can always go home or press back until they have finished all your activities.